# Create project on remote server and use Git from remote server in JetBrains PhpStorm

Tags: git, ssh, visual-studio-code, phpstorm, sftp

As the title suggests, I'm interesting in finding out how I can create a PhpStorm project on a remote server and handle the version controlling using the git from that remote server.

This feature is similar to VSCode's remote connection extension (where editing and git is all done on a remote server via SSH).

I already have files and a git repo on the remote server and I want to use the "create a project from existing files" feature, but I would prefer to work completely remotely rather than having a local copy. By default this option creates a local copy of my remote server and all git interactions are for the local copy of the project. If it would be easier, I'm willing to work with a local copy of the project, but I would like PhpStorm's VCS to be for the remote server.

I'm fairly new to PhpStorm, but have experience working with JetBrains' other IDEs (like IntelliJ and PyCharm).

Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, there's no way to achieve that in PhpStorm (or PyCharm, or IDEA) as per 2019.3.
Please vote: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-143172